# Cannot Install Node.js. Error: "GLIBC_2.16"

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install node.js on my new RPi2 ... but I'm getting an error after I install.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb
--2015-09-15 23:06:03--  http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb
Resolving node-arm.herokuapp.com (node-arm.herokuapp.com)... 204.236.218.45
Connecting to node-arm.herokuapp.com (node-arm.herokuapp.com)|204.236.218.45|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5465884 (5.2M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: `node_latest_armhf.deb.2'

100%[======================================>] 5,465,884   1.50M/s   in 4.3s    

2015-09-15 23:06:08 (1.20 MB/s) - `node_latest_armhf.deb.2' saved [5465884/5465884]


pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo dpkg -i node_latest_armhf.deb
(Reading database ... 83650 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace node 4.0.0-1 (using node_latest_armhf.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement node ...
Setting up node (4.0.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ node -v
    node: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by node)
    node: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node)
```

But I just installed node, so I don't know what "GLIBC_2.16" is?

Any suggestions?

Comment: The linked web page has specific instructions.  Did you follow them?

Comment: According to this https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=98079&p=687477 you need to have upgraded to Debian Jessie

Answer (score 3):

Steve Robillard was correct. I need to install Debian Jessie.

Comment: http://sjoerd.luon.net/posts/2015/02/debian-jessie-on-rpi2/

Comment: You should expand your answer to include the steps needed to do this, and add a link to full instructions for reference.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with stock Raspbian, Adafruit has a [repository](https://learn.adafruit.com/apt-adafruit-com/installing-packages) that includes, among other things, Node v0.12.6.

```
~/ghost% node -v
v0.12.6
~/ghost% lsb_release -d
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)
```

It allowed me to get a *more current* version (though not the latest) of node up and running within minutes on my existing Raspbian installs on older model Bs, although you really need a 2B to run anything heavy.

Comment: version 0.13.6 is not the latest 4.x is.

Comment: OP doesn't specify what version is needed, only that it's needed. Wheezy's got 0.6.19, so 0.12.6 is a big improvement, even if not the latest. I found I could get ghost running on it. Just pointing out that you can get a *more* current, even if not the latest, version without going to jessie. OP's requirements are unclear.

Comment: Did you see this in the question? Setting up node (4.0.0-1) or this http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb  Also the version installed version of GLIBC is not an issue until 4.x

Comment: I just read it as "setting up node on RPi2". Looks like @Vikas Putcha may have a better alternative for Wheezy, so upvoting his. I'll give it a go on raspbian wheezy when I get a chance. Just wary of a wholesale recommendation to go to wheezy without other considerations.

Comment: @Steve Robillard - I just realized my answer was misleading. Edited to reflect *more current* version. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2):

Try the latest Release from nodejs 4.1 from its website. It worked for me.

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v4.1.0/node-v4.1.0-linux-armv6l.tar.xz

Pick the kit that suits your architecture.

Comment: Was this on wheezy or jessie?